# wxgrid cell renderer set col size

Tags: python, wxpython, wxgrid

I made a  class whic extends PyGridCellRenderer and I can set size of columns with 
self.colSize = SOME_SIZE, but that sets same size for all columns, how can I set size for specific column?

Comment: Have you tried `grid.SetColSize(index, size)`?

Comment: I tried, it cant recognize variable grid, undefined variable.

Comment: I mean, you can try to set column sizes by calling `SetColSize` method of the wxgrid itself.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I need to do it from PyGridCellRenderer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SetCellSize(row, col, num_rows, num_cols);
```

Thissets the cell at the coordinates row, col to flow over num_rows rows and num_col
columns.

If this is not what you want and want to work with pixel then:

```
SetColSize(col, width);
SetRowSize(row, height);
```

you can determine the current size of a row or column using :

```
GetColSize(col)
GetRowSize(row)
```

Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: It works in Grid class, but I wanted to do it in PyGridCellRenderer class which is passed as plugin parameter to Grid class, so I can have only one Grid class and change only plugins that are passed to Grid constructor...But it seems I cant acces grid from PyGridCellRenderer...